# How to make a radio button read-only but not disabled?

Tags: html, disabled-input, readonly-attribute

The question "How to make radio button read-only?" has already been asked `n` times. But the solution is always `disabled="disabled"`.

(There can also be complicated JavaScript solutions, that work with the `click` or `change` event and prevent the value's change, but all that has usually a smell of a more or less dirty hack.)

The problem / side effect of `disabled="disabled"` is, that it "removes" the field from the data set and it then isn't sent to the server.

What I want is to make the radio buttons read-only / not changeable -- but in the same time to let them be sent to the server on form submit. `disabled` doesn't meet this requirement, `readonly` seems not to work for radio buttons.

**What is the correct HTML attribute for making a radio button read-only without to remove it from the form data set?**

Comment: why not just use an image and a hidden field?

Answer (score 7):

Try using some CSS:

```
input[type="radio"].readonly {
  opacity: 0.5; /* not necessary */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Would just like to point out that `pointer-events` has some issues with IE (http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20pointer-events) but then why would you be using IE in the first place.

Comment: Great answer!!  If I might enhance it, you'll also need identical label.readonly CSS if the radio button has a label, and you will also need to set tabindex="-1" for the radio and label elements so the user cannot tab over to the elements and select them with the spacebar.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you mean. That you have a `radio button` which has a value and you don't want the value to be removed or changed but you want to display it to a user maybe to notify his consent. Then I think this should work.

Giving the `radio button` a `name` attribute which is assigned to it alone and also the `checked` attribute like this.

```
<input type="radio " name="my_radio_btn" value="its_value" checked />
```

This way, the user can't uncheck it

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but `checked` needs a value -- `checked` or an empty string (s. [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html#input.radio.attrs.checked)). And `checked=""` doesn't prevent changes.

Comment: So have you found a solution to your question?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The only clean solution would be an attribute like `readonly`. Everything else is a more or less dirty workaround. But there seems not to be such an attribute (yet).

Answer (score 0):

This might seem a bit hacky but you could just set the value of the radio button to be its initial state when the `onclick` event is fired for it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="button1" type="radio" onmouseover="setValue(this)" onclick="retainValue(this)" checked> Radio Example
    <input id="button2" type="radio" onmouseover="setValue(this)" onclick="retainValue(this)"> Radio Example
    <script>
      var checkboxes = {};
      function setValue(el) {
        if(!(el.id in checkboxes))
          checkboxes[el.id] = el.checked;
      }
      function retainValue(el) {
        if(!(el.id in checkboxes))
          checkboxes[el.id] = el.checked;
        el.checked = checkboxes[el.id];
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It allows you to have as many radios as you want on the page provided each one has a unique id.

If you're willing to use jQuery then it would be a lot easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Provided one of the read-only radio buttons is initially checked, you could disable all other radio buttons in the group:

```
<input name="my_field" value="A" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
<input name="my_field" value="B" type="radio" disabled="disabled"/>
…
```

Then the user cannot effectively click anywhere to change; but the checked input will generate the response field.